# WPF 'Map' control; using canvas to display lots of bitmap images

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm parsing minecraft file data using Substrate. Minecraft is made up of 'chunks', which are made up of blocks. So I've got a spritesheet with the different 16x16 tiles. I use a croppedbitmap in WPF to find the appropriate graphic tile to make up a section of the map. Then I assign an Image() control in WPF the 'source', which is my croppedbitmap. Finally, I do myCanvas.Children.Add(myImage)... The problem is that after about 30 or so images in my canvas, the application slows to a crawl. This is a problem because typical minecraft maps will have hundreds or thousands of images. Is there a better way to draw a large amount of bitmap data? I like having Image controls because then I can put tooltips on the map and make it interactive. But I accept that an Image control is probably way more expensive and having thousands of them may not work. Here's my code. 
(this only parses tiles of a certain value, hence if id == 9)

```
     var mapTiles = (BitmapImage)FindResource("mapTiles");
         CroppedBitmap waterImage = new CroppedBitmap(mapTiles, new Int32Rect(352, 48, 16, 16));
         CroppedBitmap grassImage = new CroppedBitmap(mapTiles, new Int32Rect(0, 0, 16, 16));
         foreach (ChunkRef chunk in chunkManager)
         {
             countOfTiles++;

             for (int x = 0; x <= 15; x++)
             {
                 for (int z = 0; z <= 15; z++)
                 {
                     int height = chunk.Blocks.GetHeight(x, z);
                     //TODO: Normalize Chunk X, Z so 0,0 is the smallest chunk so everything is visible on the canvas.
                     if (height > 0 && chunk.X > 0 && chunk.Z > 0)
                     {
                         var block = chunk.Blocks.GetBlock(x, height - 1, z);

                         if (block.ID == 9)
                         {
                             //352, 48
                             Image image = new Image();
                             image.Source = waterImage;
                             worldMap.Children.Add(image);
                             Canvas.SetTop(image, (chunk.X + x) * 16);
                             Canvas.SetLeft(image, (chunk.Z + z) * 16);
                             image.ToolTip = countOfTiles.ToString();
                         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the heavier Image, you could use an ImageBrush:

```
// use ImageBrush's instead
var waterImage = new ImageBrush(new CroppedBitmap(...));
var grassImage = new ImageBrush(new CroppedBitmap(...));

waterImage.Freeze();
grassImage.Freeze();
```

Later:

```
if (block.ID == 9)
{
    var water = new Rectangle
    {
        Width = 16,
        Height = 16,
        Fill = waterImage
    };
    worldMap.Children.Add(water);
    Canvas.SetTop(water, (chunk.X + x) * 16);
    Canvas.SetLeft(water, (chunk.Z + z) * 16);
    water.ToolTip = countOfTiles.ToString();
}
```

If I leave out Freeze, I can't get a test app with a 100x100 tile world to display properly. When I freeze each of the brushes, I can get the map to display seamlessly up to about 300x300. At 1000x1000 it almost does not load, but at this point you need to [consider virtualizing the view](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/tags/virtualizingtilepanel/) as the UI won't handle that many UIElement's gracefully.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's amazing how much faster this approach ends up being. One correction: Instead of the 'Background' property on the Rectangle, I used 'Fill'. I think that's just a typo because I couldn't find a background property.

Comment: You're correct, it was a typo. It may even be worth designing a lightweight `Control` which encapsulates some subset of chunks. Also, you'll have to move to a virtualizing panel at some point in World Sizes.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by virtualizing the view. can you provide some links or other info on this? Again, really appreciate the input!

Comment: Basically it abstracts away the children of a control such that a smaller number of UI Elements are reused with different bound data rather than thousands of individual UI elements. [A good series of articles from Dan Crevier covers making a virtualizing panel.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/tags/virtualizingtilepanel/)